# Animation Node and the Different Ways to Make Grids

Tags: animation-nodes

What are the differences between these two Grids? And why use Animation Node instead of the array modifier?

[image: Grid 1]

[image: Grid 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the *Object Instancer* node, you are basically duplicating the object while keeping the same mesh data block. When using the *Replicate Mesh* node, you are constructing a single mesh by replicating the source mesh along the input transformations.

The array modifier would be roughly equivalent to the replication method, however, it is very limited when it comes to the patterns that you can generate.

Comment: Thank you. So it was difficult to use the maprange to modify the size of mesh objects according to distance.